# How do I do a proper if statement with data from a serial device in python?

Tags: python, pyserial

I'm reading in serial data from a serial USB device with python.
I want to compare the received data with a predefined string if it matches.
Reading the data works fine the problem is this if-statement:

```
if serialInst.in_waiting:
    startPacket =  serialInst.readline()    
    z = "iohioowwcncuewqrte"
    k = startPacket.decode('utf').rstrip('\n')
    if (k == z):
        print("right passkey")
    else:
        print("Error") 
        exit()
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's not a [mcve].  What *exactly* is the problem?  If "reading the data works" what is the value of `startPacket`?

Comment: It's likely the serialial device is sending `\r` or `\r\n` as the newline sequence. Strip them both.

Comment: There are two `if` statements. Which one is the problem?

Comment: You can use `print(repr(k))` to see the exact value of `k` including possible special characters.

Comment: thank you very much it's right i have to strip \r too.